# Control isn't getting the Selected value from DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I got the following Model:

```
public class ViewBloqueioNotaFiscal
{

   public ViewComboStatus ComboStatus = new ViewComboStatus();

   public class ViewComboStatus
   {
      public int? IdStatusSelecionado { get; set; }
      public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ComboStatus { get; set; }
   }
}
```

The following controller method:

```
public ViewBloqueioNotaFiscal.ViewComboStatus geraComboStatus(int? statusSelecionado)
{
   ViewBloqueioNotaFiscal.ViewComboStatus combo = new ViewBloqueioNotaFiscal.ViewComboStatus
   {
       IdStatusSelecionado = statusSelecionado,     
       ComboStatus = new[]{
                     new SelectListItem { Value = 1, Text = "Op1"},
                     new SelectListItem { Value = 2, Text = "Op2"}
        }
   };
   return combo;
}
```

And my aspx is like:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ComboStatus.IdStatusSelecionado, Model.ComboStatus.ComboStatus) %>
```

Its getting perfectly displayed for selection but when I submit my form, my post method from controller gets the model perfectly with the values except for this combo that Im recieving null value into the model. As its the first one that I try, I think that something is wrong.

Could you guys check that for me? If you have any better solution for this I d like to know too.

thanks for the help !

Comment: Values come only when they are selected. Are you sure something is selected out of the combobox while u r submitting by post method?

Comment: Yeah.. I just got the two options..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not binding to the correct property of your view model. You are binding to some complex object (`ComboStatus`) which doesn't make sense.

You should bind the drop down list to the `IdStatusSelecionado` property:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.ComboStatus.IdStatusSelecionado, 
    Model.ComboStatus.ComboStatus
) %>
```

A strongly typed DropDownListFor helper requires at least 2 things on your view model:

1. A scalar property (int, decimal, string, ...) which will be used to bind to
2. A collection of value/text pairs.

If the collection of value/text pairs contains an item whose value is equal to the scalar property you used as first argument, this item will be preselected. For example if you wanted to preselect the second item in your example you would set `IdStatusSelecionado=2` on your view model.

Side note: `Model.ComboStatus.ComboStatus` looks terrible. Please rename.

Comment: thanks for the help,bro ! Ill rename it. Anyway, I just forgot to put the IdStatusSelecionado  porperty here, but my code is with that. And I have the same problem ( even with x => x.ComboStatus.IdStatusSelecionado..)

Comment: @Dan-SP, this means that the value of the IdStatusSelecionado is not found as value in the ComboStatus collection. You may also try the following: `ComboStatus = new SelectList(new[] { new SelectListItem { Value = 1, Text = "Op1"}, new SelectListItem { Value = 2, Text = "Op2" }, "Value", "Text", statusSelecionado)` when assigning the `ComboStatus` property in your action.